# How to record voice in "wav" format in Android

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

I have written a piece of code in Android that records audio in `.3gpp format`, but I need to record it in `.wav format`. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: A 2011 blog post covering this issue is mentioned in comments on an answer. The latest archive of the blog post is [2015-06-26](//web.archive.org/web/20150626112354/http://i-liger.com/article/android-wav-audio-recording). The earliest archive of the blog post/code is from [2011-04-15/16](//web.archive.org/web/20110415083040/http://i-liger.com/article/android-wav-audio-recording). The latest archive of the blog's code is [2015-06-17](//web.archive.org/web/20150901000000*/http://i-liger.com/sites/default/files/ExtAudioRecorder.java).