# how to record .wav files in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to record .wav format file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245497/how-to-record-wav-format-file-in-android)

I would like to record .wav files using android. is there any way to do this...anybody help me...
thanks in advance